# Showing continuity of a map

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(S, \rho)$ be a compact metric space. Suppose the map $T: S \to S$ is such that for every $x \neq y$, $$\rho(Tx, Ty) < \rho(x,y)$$ 1) Show that the map $\phi: S \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\phi(x) = \rho(x, Tx)$ is continuous.

2) Show that $T$ has a unique fixed point. That is, there exists a unique $x_0 \in S$ s.t. $T(x_0) = x_0$

Well, we have our function phi(x) = rho(x,Tx) and T is a map S->S with the property phi(Tx,Ty) < phi(x,y) s.t. x \neq y. We know that since S is compact, there are convergent sequences (x_n) which converge in S. For phi to be continuous, then we must have that (x_n) -> c => phi(x_n) -> phi(c).

This is where I stop though since I don't really know how to continue. Maybe we can say 'Suppose not;', then take the negation of the continuity statement.

Would the triangle inequality tell us anything useful? (yes, yes it does)

Comment: This is Banachs fixed-point theorem.

Comment: @AlexR, isn't. More is required.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Would you elaborate? Note that the constant of convergence for BFP exists because $S$ is compact.

Comment: @AlexR, BFPT requires $d(...)\le k d(...)$, $0<k<1$. But also requires less: complete vs compact. In a typical application (vgr Picard-Lindelof) $k$ is "adjustable", so the weaker condition isn't adventageous, but the space isn't compact.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla But it remains an application of BFPT since all conditions are met, correct?

Comment: @AlexR, yes, is a consequence of BFPT.

Answer (score 0):

start with triangle inequality
p(x,Tx) <= p(x,y) + p(y,Ty) + p(Ty,Tx)
then rearrange and use the premise
p(x,Tx) - p(y,Ty) <= p(x,y) + p(Ty,Tx) <= 2p(x,y)
symmetrically, the same holds with x,y swapped, so
|p(x,Tx) - p(y,Ty)| <= 2p(x,y).

From here we use this with the epsilon-delta definition of continuity.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the uniqueness part,

Consider $x \neq y$ and $x,y$ are fixed points of $\phi$. Note that $\rho(Tx,Ty) < \rho(x,y)$. We know that $Tx = x$ and $Ty = y$, so this tells us that $\rho(x,y) < \rho(x,y)$. A contridiction.